# Laravel 5.6 using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to use AJAX to get sorted products off of a database. However AJAX keeps sending this error.

> exception: "ErrorException"
>   ​​
>   file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\WebProject\storage\framework\views\c39cbea2eafe7197b8efb68251988b2c5b3a6834.php"
>   ​​
>   line: 5
>   ​​
>   message: "Trying to get property 'URL' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\WebProject\resources\views\producto_indiv.blade.php)"

The thing is that the view producto_indiv has no connection to the javascript code for ajax. The view where the error comes from shows no errors when being accessed.

This is the producto_indiv, where the error is supposed to come from, however this view is unrelated to the one with the ajax code

```
<div class="contenedor" id="Producto_Indiv_Page">
  <div class="item-cont">
    <?php $url = "/storage/images/products/" . basename($producto->URL); ?>
    <img src="{{$url}}">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="traits">
      <div><span class="name">{{$producto->nombre_prod}}</span></div>
      <span>Precio: ${{$producto->precio}}</span>
      <span>Descripcion: {{$producto->descripcion}}</span>
      <span>marca: {{$producto->marca}}</span>
      <span>tamanos: {{$producto->tamanos}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

AJAX code

```
$('.sort_opt').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
  jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/ropa/sort',
    data: {
      type: this.name,
      genero: this.gender,
    },
    success: function(result) {
      console.log("DONE");
    },
    error: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
});
```

and controller

```
  public function sort(Request $request) {
    $producto = DB::table('productos')->where('$request->genero')->get();
    switch($request->type) {
      case 'nombre':
        $producto->orderBy('nombre_prod', 'asc');
        break;
      case 'marca':
        $producto->orderBy('marca', 'asc');
        break;
      case 'precio_desc':
        $producto->orderBy('precio', 'desc');
        break;
      case 'precio_desc':
        $producto->orderBy('precio', 'desc');
        break;
      case 'new':
        $producto->latest();
        break;
      case 'old':
        $producto->oldest();
        break;
    }

      return \Response::json($producto);
  }
```

I have been stuck on this before but changed to using redirects instead of ajax, however in this I cannot do that due to the fact that I am trying to sort a grid of products, sent from the DB.

Comment: Can you share your `ropa/sort` route ? Are you sure it points to the function you've shared? Your sort function is wrong. You need to not call `get()` until after the switch to ensure the query additions actually work.

Comment: @apokryfos These are the two routes, the id one is the one accessing the individual files, where the error seems to be from and the sort is the one I am trying to make work
Route::get('/ropa/{id}', 'PagesControl@viewItem')->name('item');
Route::get('/ropa/sort', 'PagesControl@sort');

Comment: if `ropa/{id}` is declared before `ropa/sort` it will override it.

Comment: How come, Aren't they different?? 
Anyways, changed the route for the sort, same 500 internal server error, though the message changed to "<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\\[\\]\\/\\\\])/g, idRx = /\\bsf-dump-\\d+-ref[012]\\w+\\b/, [...]"

Comment: `/ropa/sort` matches `/ropa/{id}` when `id = sort` the error probably relates to the other point I made before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things wrong here:

1. Your route ropa/{id} overrides /ropa/sort because it matches when id="sort" so you need to either put the ropa/sort route before the ropa/{id} route.
2. You are calling `->get()` which executes the query and subsequently you are adding query constraints. That will not work since the query is already executed.
3. You have `where('$request->genero')` that that does not actually use any variable because you've wrapped it in a string.
4. `where('$request->genero')` does not have a column to filter by, the syntax would be `where('genero', $request->genero)`

Putting all these 4 together I can say :

Put the ropa/sort before the ropa/{id} route.

Change your `sort()` code to:

```
public function sort(Request $request) {
    $producto = DB::table('productos')->where('genero', $request->genero);
    switch($request->type) {
        case 'nombre':
            $producto->orderBy('nombre_prod', 'asc');
            break;
        case 'marca':
            $producto->orderBy('marca', 'asc');
            break;
        case 'precio_desc':
            $producto->orderBy('precio', 'desc');
            break;
        case 'precio_desc':
            $producto->orderBy('precio', 'desc');
            break;
       case 'new':
            $producto->latest();
            break;
       case 'old':
            $producto->oldest();
            break;
      }

     return \Response::json($producto->get());

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude, this solved the issue, I didn't know routes would override like that

Answer (score 0):

This problem has arrived because your *$producto* object has no Url, so please check first the **$producto->URL** and then pass the URL as below way.

```
<?php 
$productURl = "";
if(isset($producto->URL)) {
  $productURl = $producto->URL;
}

?>

<div class="contenedor" id="Producto_Indiv_Page">
  <div class="item-cont">
    <?php $url = "/storage/images/products/" . basename($productURl); ?>
    <img src="{{$url}}">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="traits">
      <div><span class="name">{{$producto->nombre_prod}}</span></div>
      <span>Precio: ${{$producto->precio}}</span>
      <span>Descripcion: {{$producto->descripcion}}</span>
      <span>marca: {{$producto->marca}}</span>
      <span>tamanos: {{$producto->tamanos}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the thing is that I am not going into that site. these are my routes for each. 
Route::get('/ropa/{id}', 'PagesControl@viewItem')->name('item');
Route::get('/ropa/sort', 'PagesControl@sort');
Also when I load the page, there are no errors at all and every object loads correctly. I have checked the DB in case it was a null calue somewhere, yet it is complete.

Comment: The error says: "Trying to get property 'URL' of **non-object**". That means `$producto` is not an object. What does `dd($producto);` output?

Comment: here it is the dd for any product 
{#463 ▼
  +"id": 14
  +"nombre_prod": "Camisa Roja"
  +"cantidad": 10
  +"precio": 250.0
  +"marca": "tommy"
  +"genero": "hombre"
  +"tamanos": "small"
  +"descripcion": "camisa para hombre"
  +"URL": "public/images/products/kMqMky8ol9qc8ih2OqLvGlMNPtYVX49OR0eyaGbL.jpeg"
  +"created_at": "2018-04-10 20:48:07"
  +"updated_at": "2018-04-10 20:48:07"
}

Comment: Can you please change the $producto = DB::table('productos')->where('$request->genero')->get(); replace with the DB::table('productos')->where($request->genero)->get(); line. Remove single qoute romeve in your controller inside db query

Comment: @NissimBet You did that in your view?

Comment: @Mike Yes the dd is from the view.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd done, same 500 internal error, the message changed
"<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\\[\\]\\/\\\\])/g, idRx = /\\bsf-dump-\\d+-ref[012]\\w+\\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); };